# Calling function inside if statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement

im trying to call function inside if statement but it does not work. This is one of my first attempts in using Python. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python


menu = raw_input ("Hello, please choose form following options (1,2,3) and press enter:\n"
    "Option 1\n"
    "Option 2\n"
    "Option 3\n")

if menu == str("1"):
    savinginfile = raw_input ("Please, state your name: ")
    option1()
elif menu == str("2"):
    print ("Option 2")
elif menu == str("3"):
    print ("Option 3")

def option1():
    test = open ("test.txt", "rw")
    test.write(savinginfile)
    print ("Option 1 used")
    test.close()
```

Comment: What doesn't work ?? You get an error code ?? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

Would recommend that you pass `savinginfile` as a parameter:

```
def option1(savinginfile):
    test = open ("test.txt", "rw")
    test.write(savinginfile)
    print ("Option 1 used")
    test.close()
```

You need to define `option1` before calling. Python interprets from top to bottom.

Comment: Just a minor correction, in JD's code, savinginfile as a global variable is not out of scope inside option1. option1() will automatically search global namespace. The only problem is option1 is undefined before call. As you suggested, passing savinginfile as a parameter and defining option1 before calling is the right way to solve it

Comment: @TwistedMeadow You're right! Still bad practice, but I will update my answer (above) to reflect that.

Comment: good catch @TwistedMeadow, didn't notice the `if else` was at top level. answer changed

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your function before you try to call it. Just put `def option1(): #and all that code below it` above your if statements.

It's also bad practice to throw around too many global variables. You shouldn't use `savinginfile` the way you are -- instead, pass it to the function as a parameter and let the function operate in its own scope. You'll need to pass the function the name of the file to use before it's able to use `savinginfile`. Try instead:

```
def option1(whattosaveinfile):
  test = open("test.txt","a+") #probably better to use a with statement -- I'll comment below.
  test.write(whattosaveinfile) #note that you use the parameter name, not the var you pass to it
  print("Option 1 used")
  test.close()

#that with statement works better for file-like objects because it automatically
#catches and handles any errors that occur, leaving you with a closed object.
#it's also a little prettier :) Use it like this:
#
# with open("test.txt","a+") as f:
#   f.write(whattosaveinfile)
# print("Option 1 used")
#
#note that you didn't have to call f.close(), because the with block does that for you
#if you'd like to know more, look up the docs for contextlib

if menu == "1": #no reason to turn this to a string -- you've already defined it by such by enclosing it in quotes
  savinginfile = raw_input("Please state your name: ")
  option1(savinginfile) #putting the var in the parens will pass it to the function as a parameter.

elif menu == "2": #etc
#etc
#etc
```

Comment: You can't open a file in `rw` mode (it doesn't exist).  I think it would be best to use `a+` here.

Comment: Noted and edited in the answer. (I don't frankly deal with read/write to files very much -- I have to look it up each time)